# Unable to get my custom JSF Login Portlet working

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, websphere, portlet, portal

I am using webSphere portal 6.1. I wrote my own custom login portlet and placed in the Login page from the portal server. The page loads fine the problem is when I try to login. It takes 2 attempts to login. The first time when I try to login, the page refreshes (I don’t see any exception on the consol). If I enter the user id/password for the second time, the login works perfectly

After extensive debugging this is what I found,

The first time when I try to login, the process action get called but it skips the managed bean and call the doView. The second time, the process action get called and the managed bean get called (login is successful) and then the doView get called. So I decided to take a look at the html output, sure enough the action url is different. The url for initil load is

action="/wps/portal/esb/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3h355AAV0dnEwMLPycTA8_AUINQL1cLAwNXU_1wkA6zeAMcwNFA388jPzdVvyA7rxwAtTMgag!!/dl3/d3/L0lDU0lKSkpDZ3BSQ1FvS1VRa2chL29Gb2dBRUlRaGpGRUlBQWpPTTRSa0JTVkpRcEdnZ0d0QUEhIS80QzFiOVdfTnIwUkprQWxJTVJKa1FsTUlpUi1BLzdfR0NUUEVBQzQwOEdQRDBJUTFGUVQ2MzMwRzUvaWJtLmludi8xNDc3ODc5NDM0MDAvamF2YXguc2VydmxldC5pbmNsdWRlLnBhdGhfaW5mby8lMGpzcHMlMEVTQkxvZ2luUG9ydGxldFZpZXcuanNw/”

and the url after the first attempt to log in is,

action="/wps/portal/esb/!ut/p/c5/dVBHsoPIAjvLHIAy2bCEJhswqaFh4yKZYBNMhtPP-7u_GWmhhUpSlW7J7Y99ujVVujRDn35v6JawLxUEjiwAGudskcZ1F-LQkDkcl5lbdEM4_fJbbrTOBZkX2IL2cnErKCnLzP80PixbcorQg6IgXFALwr9M8r9W_D8g4DdbG7ryFt-S-_9tq470t00obsBSFK4yt-CGxtAzP6zOKQ6-zFgbhmonj9NYXMDQBZUQSxfpYzX7SkSCADgOujiRZCdG-60JFN3PGnR5ybH8ZXU5DtZ3H1rY88xwaBE5IwQ6x78oXEfRuiOKe9WXyAopGRCQT_jDM42lgrK_TGHPyk-g1J1S-d9w_CXXFcO_Nz49ZsTpSe_VZ45OkgeOdG8eFNi-pdxYCUTWZOMSJkG2DCBGqB1QdVeiqf5pqJEu9gleebgMHtuTNt37IR4IXqU4HbNYNN40KyO1W3lh7NR3sOewBJKX1KXWEFelg2lciJqklUX068fRNUzJuNUulevvXrnRbAaWZEhBWddE9qM1_gMrffrp9fjouTXpPMRTRGu-uMfxDn-9fE7ePjiTZ6ceGqnCfHVPzh7ucwV7sx8rwNEGm1JCVPQaa715RygFAiwcr72mgQ726FrWMWPchGbrp5Th3ZY9nDL5mEXIYSaA67MPaUAs9eiMlnFalHBRYnruS0asZU_YDo2Ugbl7KJplfRRitT0nMPCzqfICQExjlJjOPT4OPIRPo3EGYarhN50qHnihCJTZIFgURycbf8IiG5wSsvS4MYITZHUqYzDcNVC7cxvIen-_msergaAj6XtBo9GuWwADk8xSfb5jCslG0O8uem8wILCTobn3VGKkMHQ3xR9Xw5y9MoGHeKEaG0I5_JB2kmOW2eWTiJY4i9o6bLxzPwM5nwGSAif8fqCuffi36iX0Pu1OgcsF_95QIhOKKYUv9prKxO_6xbf3WmOSaJCDLfrRpPaK3CYnHFkt8oxodC8uG2fvJ2F4aLYyMd6vrb1IbL2fgESn2LPEf4ZSkH6PeaKONvL9mm5Prguu8ZvwMPzk7z6b1_OLI5iox6ivHBoZb32Y0far1f7atWl0jpaUYilQd9xIClj36LL3oTjZNbLmTiKaQcH8dcea7YFayk8bk3S2dC_8cn9afvJQ6ZAzOd-_cInXqhfj7eWb5Jj4nbXKK4k9mmJw6358T99Yvx1Rqpf6fj_FnJiKsQlPn7g7x1tjrwMTxvI3GbTALcHCI3fl-zw2rT_bYvONm7glRu93peJk7zG3sdtGzhb--RcqYJzK/dl3/d3/L0lDU0lKSkthWWtLQ2xFWm1ZQSEhL29Pb2dBRUlRaGpCS0VRQUFBRVpDZ0dRNEtRcGNFb2lBWUFEUkVBd0FCaUlCZ0FMRVFEQUFBQSEhLzRDMWI5V19OcnhRREVTWklKUkNBLzdfR0NUUEVBQzQwOEdQRDBJUTFGUVQ2MzMwRzUvMTQ3Nzg3OTY4NTYzL2phdmF4LnNlcnZsZXQuaW5jbHVkZS5wYXRoX2luZm8vJTBqc3BzJTBFU0JMb2dpblBvcnRsZXRWaWV3LmpzcA!!/"

Can some please explain me what going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found a solution for my problem. it seems that JSF is trying to save it's viewstate in the session, but public session is not enabled by default for anonymous user. So changing the state saving method in web.xml from server to client seem to do the trick